# Get unique id of row just inserted into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that submits super basic information, just a new name (the name gets assigned a unique id). What I am trying to make happen is when the user submits the name it gets submitted into the database and they get redirected to a new page card.php where they can add more specific information. However the unique id associated with the row that was just submitted needs to follow in the URL (id=$id)

```
$query = "INSERT INTO name VALUES(NULL, '$name')";

mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query2);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $id = $row['id'];
}

header("Location: http://localhost/card.php?id=$id");
```

**Process**

addName.php -> user submits new name -> add to database -> redirect to card.php WITH unique id value of name that is just submitted

1.) Is there a way to retain the id of the row just submitted? In the fluke chance 2 or more people submit at the same time the second query of getting the last row inserted into the database will return the wrong row id 
2). Having a while loop return 1 piece of info seems like a shitty way to do things, this might be the most basic of shit but i cant seem to return the 1 piece of data without doing this

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php Do you even bother to read manuals?

Comment: sometimes we dont know what exact function we are looking for bud, you dont know what else ive tried and what else ive searched for. A simple link post wouldve been sufficient enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `mysqli_insert_id` which returns the AUTO_INCREMENT ID generated from the previous `INSERT` operation.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO name VALUES(NULL, '$name')";

mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$id = mysqli_insert_id();

header("Location: http://localhost/card.php?id=$id");
```

**Reference:** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: he is using MYSQLI not mysql, so the function he needs is `mysqli_insert_id`

Comment: my understanding of this function based on the quick reading i did is that it pulls the unique id value of the last row inserted (perfect). Is there any reason it would return a NULL value even when the insert works fine and auto increments correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the mysqli function to retrieve the last inserted id (check [mysqli_insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) as suggested in a comment), but I wouldn't recommend you using the user id in the URL, people can try to get in, using other ids

also you can use the php function to generate a custom is check out: [uniqid](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)